# How to bind date from datagridview to datetime picker in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime, c#-4.0, datagridview

I have column name "Session" in table which store data as "2010-2014" etc format and i get this string from two date time pickers  as:

```
string dat = dateTimePicker1.Text + "-" + dateTimePicker2.Text;
```

i set datetimepicker property as Year only so it gave me result as when i selected dates
"2010-2014"

In Insertion this is working good but for updation i need to load this value back to date time pickers as  it e-g in datetimepicker1 text must be 2010 and in datetimepicker2 text must be 2014 according to my example.

i made a lot of search on google and did this as:

```
                string str = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            string first = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf('-'));
            string second = str.Substring(str.IndexOf('-') + 1);

            dateTimePicker1.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(first).ToString();
            dateTimePicker2.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(second).ToString();
```

But it threw an error that:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime
```

I am using c# windows app development.

Any body has any idea where am i missing something?
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this

```
dateTimePicker1.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(first).ToString();
```

to

```
dateTimePicker1.SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(first);
```

You converted to a date, and then back to a string again!!

---

In all honesty, you would be better storing two dates (start and finish), rather than just the years because a date is made up of day/month/year and i have a feeling you may actually need to do the following to make it actually work ...

```
dateTimePicker1.SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/" + first);
```

... that way you end up with a valid date (01/01/2015) that can be converted from a string.

Comment: i did this already but intelecence give me error as "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'string' "

Comment: Yes, my bad, you need to assign to `SelectedDate` rather than `Text`

Comment: Thanks this works for me now by adding "01/01/" this string.